# email verification not working in flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, email-verification

Here i am calling my home in main.dart
Now if i am not verify my email it is still redirecting me to my First_Page instead of Sign_In_Page.

```
 home: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.emailVerified==null?Sign_In_Page():First_Page(),
```

This is my email verifaication page which i am navigating after user signup with a email id and passowrd

```
  final auth=FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late User user;
  late Timer timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
   user=auth.currentUser!;
   user.sendEmailVerification();
   timer=Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
     emailverify();
   });
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Text(
            "An Email verification link has been sent to you, Please verify..",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
   Future<void> emailverify() async{
    user=auth.currentUser!;
    await user.reload();
    if(user.emailVerified){
      timer.cancel();
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>First_Page()));
    }
}
}
```

I am getting the email for verification but if i didn't verify it, it still redirecting me to my app. I think there is some problem in my code.
Plz help me in correcting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly the problem is in your check for email verification. It should be

```
(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.emailVerified ?? false) ? First_Page() : Sign_In_Page()
```

Your code was checking whether the optional `emailVerified` is not `null`, it would work only if no user is authenticated as it will be `null` as `currentUser` is null. But if a user already exists even if he's not verified the result will not be equal to `null` and your check fails and goes to app page.